# Delays to Sleep and Wake notifications

Tags: sleep-wake, notifications, power-management, kernel, energy

Is it normal that there are Kernel Client Acks every so often while my Mac is asleep indicating that there are delays on several drivers? I found entries like this via the command: `pmset -g log | grep -i "Wake\|Sleep\|Event\|Energy"`.

Example:

```
2023-11-12 11:18:45 +0100 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications
Driver x is slow...
```

I should also add that my battery suddenly dropped 4% between 2 sleep cycles.